# Question regarding implicant chart of Quine-McCluskey algorithm

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine-McCluskey#Example, at the end of Step 1, there is a table that shows the number of 1's, minterms, 0-cube and size-2 implicants and size-4 implicants. But I am not sure how each row is constructed - how minterms are related to each size-2 implicant and size-4 implicant. Can anyone explain this?